# NLP/ TF-IDF: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp, tf-idf

I'm using TF-IDF to create a content based recommendation system, I'm getting this error when trying to implement a function to output the actual recommendations of the TF-IDF model I have built. Apologies about the formatting, I'm new to this:

```
# Build a 1-dimensional array with book titles
titles = new_df['Movie Title']
indices = pd.Series(new_df.index, index=new_df['Movie Title'])

# Function that takes in movie title as input and outputs most similar movies
def get_recommendations(title):
    
    # Get the index of the movie that matches the title
    idx = indices[title]

    # Get the pairwsie similarity scores of all movies with that movie
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))

    # Sort the movies based on the similarity scores
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Get the scores of the 10 most similar movies
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:11]

    # Get the movie indices
    movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]

    # Return the top 10 most similar movies
    return new_df['Movie Title'].iloc[movie_indices]

Next code block:

 get_recommendations('The Hangover')

 get_recommendations.head(10)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-4e788498ba09> in <module>
----> 1 get_recommendations('The Hangover')
      2 get_recommendations.head(10)

<ipython-input-22-98000fdd3df8> in get_recommendations(title)
     13 
     14     # Sort the movies based on the similarity scores
---> 15     sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
     16 
     17     # Get the scores of the 10 most similar movies

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: You may need to check the value of `x[1]`. This blog article has a good explanation: https://www.akashmittal.com/valueerror-truth-value-array-ambiguous/

Comment: It's having problems doing `<` type comparisons on the values you are trying to sort.  What is `sim_scores` like, or it you prefer the `indices` Series its derived from?

Answer (score 0):

This error can be when there are same movie titles name with different index i.e lets say movie title is 'The Godfather' so it is possible that it has :

```
movie  title          index
The    Godfather      0
The    Godfather      1
The    Godfather      2
```

So to overcome this problem drop the duplicate values form the dataframe and then run the program it must run.

```
new_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Movie Title'])
```